# Gemfire Group By functions

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Is there an option to use Group by, aggregate functions in Gemfire OQL? Couldnt find any relevant documentation. Only relevant google result points to a old version of gemfire - not sure if something has changed regarding this?

We're looking at avoiding iteration and let Gemfire do the heavy lifting.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/gemfire/108266-no-group-by-having-order-by-key-words-in-gemfire-oql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct; Pivotal GemFire does not support `GROUP BY` aggregate functions yet.

Although, you may be aware that *Pivotal GemFire* was submitted to the ASF over a year ago as the [Apache Geode project](http://geode.incubator.apache.org/).  [Recently](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/OQL+Aggregate+functions+and+UDA), the Geode engineering team added support for `GROUP BY` along with the associated aggregate functions, such as `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, `SUM`, etc

However, *Apache Geode's* and *Pivotal GemFire* have diverged significantly, so *Apache Geode* contains quite a few **new** features that *Pivotal GemFire* does not (e.g. Off-Heap memory support as well).

But, the plan is that Pivotal GemFire and Apache Geode will converge and that *Pivotal GemFire* 9.0 will be based on the *Apache Geode* core, thus inheriting all the **new** features, like Off-Heap and `GROUP BY`, etc.

I have no timeframe for when that will happen, but it is the plan.

Cheers,
John